# How can I rewrite my code to perform faster?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I inherited a database that I am trying to make faster. The solution is SQL. The problem.... I don't know how to write SQL...

Currently it is using a lot of DCount and DAvg to get the results which takes nearly 40 seconds on average. I tried reducing the amount of criteria in the code by creating queries, but it still took nearly 40 seconds to run.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo errhndlr
    Me.Visible = True
    Dim OTD, Total, FY_OTD, FY_Total As Integer
    Dim SummaryDate, FiscalDate As Date

    Me.SummaryDate = Forms!ReportForm.Form.SDate
    Me.FiscalDate = Forms!ReportForm.Form.FiscalStartDate
    SummaryDate = CDate(DateValue(Me.SummaryDate))
    FiscalDate = CDate(DateValue(Me.FiscalDate))
    Me.Printer.Orientation = acPRORLandscape

    ' Met OTD
    Me.OTD_Email = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],2) = 'E-' and [ReportDate] like '" & SummaryDate & "' and DateDiff('s',[ETA],[CompletedDate]) < 0 and [Flo_Thru_Email] = True")
    Me.OTD_PLEmail = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],2) = 'PL' and [ReportDate] like '" & SummaryDate & "' and DateDiff('s',[ETA],[CompletedDate]) < 0 and [Flo_Thru_Email] = True")
    Me.OTD_Submission = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],2) = 'DE' and [ReportDate] like '" & SummaryDate & "' and DateDiff('s',[ETA],[CompletedDate]) < 0")
    Me.OTD_LT = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Projects", "Left([ProjectID],3) = 'LT-' and Format([Sent_to_Rep], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "' and DateDiff('s',[ETA],[Sent_to_Rep]) < 0 and [Approver] = 'CD' or Left([ProjectID],3) = 'LT-' and Format([Sent_to_Rep], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "' and DateDiff('s',[ETA],[Sent_to_Rep]) < 0 and [Approver] = 'MB' or Left([ProjectID],3) = 'LT-' and Format([Sent_to_Rep], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "' and DateDiff('s',[ETA],[Sent_to_Rep]) < 0 and [Approver] = 'JP'")
    Me.OTD_Specifier = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],3) = 'SSE' and [ReportDate] like '" & SummaryDate & "' and DateDiff('s',[ETA],[CompletedDate]) < 0")

    ' Total
    Me.Total_Phone = DCount("ProjectID", "Phone_Info", "Format([EndDate], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "' and left([ProjectID], 2) = 'WI' and [EmployeeID] = 'CD' or Format([EndDate], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "' and left([ProjectID], 2) = 'WI' and [EmployeeID] = 'JP' or Format([EndDate], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "' and left([ProjectID], 2) = 'WI' and [EmployeeID] = 'MB' ")
    Me.Total_Email = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],2) = 'E-' and [ReportDate] like '" & SummaryDate & "' and [Flo_Thru_Email] = True")
    Me.Total_PLEmail = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],2) = 'PL' and [ReportDate] like '" & SummaryDate & "' and [Flo_Thru_Email] = True")
    Me.Total_Submission = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],2) = 'DE' and [ReportDate] like '" & SummaryDate & "'")
    Me.Total_LT = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Projects", "Left([ProjectID],3) = 'LT-' and Format([Sent_to_Rep], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "' and [Approver] = 'CD' or Left([ProjectID],3) = 'LT-' and Format([Sent_to_Rep], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "' and [Approver] = 'MB' or Left([ProjectID],3) = 'LT-' and Format([Sent_to_Rep], 'm/d/yyyy') = '" & SummaryDate & "' and [Approver] = 'JP'")
    Me.Total_Specifier = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],3) = 'SSE' and [ReportDate] like '" & SummaryDate & "'")

    '% OTD
    If Me.Total_Email > 0 Then
    Me.PercentOTD_Email = Me.OTD_Email / Me.Total_Email
    Else: Me.PercentOTD_Email = "0"
    End If

    If Me.Total_PLEmail > 0 Then
    Me.PercentOTD_PLEmail = Me.OTD_PLEmail / Me.Total_PLEmail
    Else: Me.PercentOTD_PLEmail = "0"
    End If

    If Me.Total_Submission > 0 Then
    Me.PercentOTD_Submission = Me.OTD_Submission / Me.Total_Submission
    Else: Me.PercentOTD_Submission = "0"
    End If

    If Me.Total_LT > 0 Then
    Me.PercentOTD_LT = Me.OTD_LT / Me.Total_LT
    Else: Me.PercentOTD_LT = "0"
    End If

    If Me.Total_Specifier > 0 Then
    Me.PercentOTD_Specifier = Me.OTD_Specifier / Me.Total_Specifier
    Else: Me.PercentOTD_Specifier = "0"
    End If

    'FY % OTD
    Dim FY_EmailMet, FY_EmailTotal, FY_PLEmailMet, FY_PLEmailTotal, FY_DrEmailMet, FY_DrEmailTotal, FY_LTMet, FY_LTTotal, FY_SSMet, FY_SSTotal As Integer

        ' FYEmail
        FY_EmailMet = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],2) = 'E-' and [ReportDate] Between #" & SummaryDate & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and DateDiff('s',[ETA],[CompletedDate]) < 0 and [Flo_Thru_Email] = True")
        FY_PLEmailMet = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],2) = 'PL' and [ReportDate] Between #" & SummaryDate & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and DateDiff('s',[ETA],[CompletedDate]) < 0 and [Flo_Thru_Email] = True")
        FY_DrEmailMet = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],2) = 'DE' and [ReportDate] Between #" & SummaryDate & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and DateDiff('s',[ETA],[CompletedDate]) < 0")
        FY_LTMet = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Projects", "Left([ProjectID],3) = 'LT-' and [Sent_to_Rep] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and DateDiff('s',[ETA],[Sent_to_Rep]) < 0 and [Approver] = 'CD' or Left([ProjectID],3) = 'LT-' and [Sent_to_Rep] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and DateDiff('s',[ETA],[Sent_to_Rep]) < 0 and [Approver] = 'MB' or Left([ProjectID],3) = 'LT-' and [Sent_to_Rep] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and DateDiff('s',[ETA],[Sent_to_Rep]) < 0 and [Approver] = 'JP'")
        FY_SSMet = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],3) = 'SSE' and [ReportDate] Between #" & SummaryDate & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and DateDiff('s',[ETA],[CompletedDate]) < 0")

        FY_EmailTotal = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],2) = 'E-' and [ReportDate] Between #" & SummaryDate & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and [Flo_Thru_Email] = True")
        FY_PLEmailTotal = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],2) = 'PL' and [ReportDate] Between #" & SummaryDate & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and [Flo_Thru_Email] = True")
        FY_DrEmailTotal = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],2) = 'DE' and [ReportDate] Between #" & SummaryDate & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "#")
        FY_LTTotal = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Projects", "Left([ProjectID],3) = 'LT-' and [Sent_to_Rep] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and [Approver] = 'CD' or Left([ProjectID],3) = 'LT-' and [Sent_to_Rep] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and [Approver] = 'MB' or Left([ProjectID],3) = 'LT-' and [Sent_to_Rep] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and [Approver] = 'JP'")
        FY_SSTotal = DCount("ProjectID", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],3) = 'SSE' and [ReportDate] Between #" & SummaryDate & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "#")

    If FY_EmailTotal > 0 Then
    Me.FYPercentOTD_Email = FY_EmailMet / FY_EmailTotal
    Else: Me.FYPercentOTD_Email = "0"
    End If

    If FY_PLEmailTotal > 0 Then
    Me.FYPercentOTD_PLEmail = FY_PLEmailMet / FY_PLEmailTotal
    Else: Me.FYPercentOTD_PLEmail = "0"
    End If

    If FY_DrEmailTotal > 0 Then
    Me.FYPercentOTD_Submission = FY_DrEmailMet / FY_DrEmailTotal
    Else: Me.FYPercentOTD_Submission = "0"
    End If

    If FY_LTTotal > 0 Then
    Me.FYPercentOTD_LT = FY_LTMet / FY_LTTotal
    Else: Me.FYPercentOTD_LT = "0"
    End If

    If FY_SSTotal > 0 Then
    Me.FYPercentOTD_Specifier = FY_SSMet / FY_SSTotal
    Else: Me.FYPercentOTD_Specifier = "0"
    End If


    ' Avg Request Age

        Me.ReqAge_Email = DAvg("ReqAge", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],2) = 'E-' and [ReportDate] Between #" & SummaryDate & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and [Flo_Thru_Email] = True")
        Me.ReqAge_PLEmail = DAvg("ReqAge", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],2) = 'PL' and [ReportDate] Between #" & SummaryDate & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and [Flo_Thru_Email] = True")
        Me.Req_Age_DraftEmail = DAvg("ReqAge", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],2) = 'DE' and [ReportDate] Between #" & SummaryDate & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "#")
        Me.ReqAge_LT = DAvg("ReqAge", "Archived_Projects", "Left([ProjectID],3) = 'LT-' and [Sent_to_Rep] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and [Approver] = 'CD' or Left([ProjectID],3) = 'LT-' and [Sent_to_Rep] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and [Approver] = 'MB' or Left([ProjectID],3) = 'LT-' and [Sent_to_Rep] Between #" & SummaryDate + 1 & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "# and [Approver] = 'JP'")
        Me.ReqAge_SSEmail = DAvg("ReqAge", "Archived_Email", "Left([ProjectID],3) = 'SSE' and [ReportDate] Between #" & SummaryDate & "# And #" & FiscalDate & "#")


    ' Summary
    Me.TotalProjects = Me.Total_Email + Me.Total_PLEmail + Me.Total_Submission + Me.Total_LT + Me.Total_Specifier
    Me.PercentOTD_Engineering = (Me.OTD_Email + Me.OTD_PLEmail + Me.OTD_Submission + Me.OTD_LT + Me.OTD_Specifier) / Me.TotalProjects
    Me.FYPercentOTD_Engineering = (FY_EmailMet + FY_PLEmailMet + FY_DrEmailMet + FY_LTMet + FY_SSMet) / (FY_EmailTotal + FY_PLEmailTotal + FY_DrEmailTotal + FY_LTTotal + FY_SSTotal)

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Gemba_OTDs", dbOpenDynaset)
    With rst
        .FindFirst "[Report_Date] = '" & DateValue(Now) & "'"
        If Not .NoMatch Then
            .Edit
            .Fields("FT_EngineeringOTD") = Me.FYPercentOTD_Engineering
            .Fields("FT_PlatinumOTD") = Me.FYPercentOTD_PLEmail
            .Fields("FT_PlatinumAge") = Me.ReqAge_PLEmail
            .Fields("FT_EmailOTD") = Me.FYPercentOTD_Email
            .Fields("FT_EmailAge") = Me.ReqAge_Email
            Else
            .AddNew
            .Fields("Report_Date") = DateValue(Now)
            .Fields("FT_EngineeringOTD") = Me.FYPercentOTD_Engineering
            .Fields("FT_PlatinumOTD") = Me.FYPercentOTD_PLEmail
            .Fields("FT_PlatinumAge") = Me.ReqAge_PLEmail
            .Fields("FT_EmailOTD") = Me.FYPercentOTD_Email
            .Fields("FT_EmailAge") = Me.ReqAge_Email

        End If
        .Update
    End With
    Set rst = Nothing
Exit Sub
errhndlr:
    Call Errhndler.ErrorHandler(Err.Number, Err.Description, Me.Name, "Form_Load")
End Sub
```

I would like to be able to cut the time down to 20 seconds or less and learn a little bit about writing in SQL. There is about 7 more reports with this type of code that all need rewritten.

Comment: Just a few points after a short view: If possible, change the table layout and extract the language part of `ProjectID` to a separate field. That would avoid string operations. Then assure that there are indexes on the tables fields which are used as a criteria. If you use a SQL server for the data, you can think about creating one or more views there.

Comment: Hire an expert. It's not the intention of this forum to provide code for free.

Comment: Thanks Unhandled Exception. I'll give that a try.

Wow Rene, what great advice! Thank you... (Eye Roll) If the company could hire an expert they likely would have. Unfortunately I'm all they have. I wasn't asking for free code I was asking how I could rewrite it to be fast. But thanks, your informative answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know SQL and your Access knowledge is on medium level , forget SQL for now and surely forget it as the "solution" for your problems.
Because people have limited knowledge and they hear that All big companies use MsSQL,Oracle,MySQL,PostGre ...they think them as the magic wand...that will "touch" the ugly duckling and transform it to a beautiful swan...
Well i hate to inform you that this is not the case...SQL is great ...but unless you treat it as Database Server you will see that it would be much much slower that the poor underrated Ms Access..... don't believe me...just upload a big table (with some million records) to SQL and try for start to open it and compare it to your Access....(if it opens it would be a small miracle)...as for CRUD...just forget it...
Now everybody will shout....wait... but we are talking about SQL Server....yes i know...but as i said above UNLESS you treat it as Database Server it won't do the miracles you expect.
As for your case...i see a lot of Domain Aggregation  (DAvg,Dcount... ) these are the worst ...they are absolute performance killers...start organizing your data so that you can get Counts/Averages/Max/Min via standard Access SQL and you will see the performance will fly...

Comment: Thanks John for explaining all that! I'll give this a try.